# connect to Remote Hive Server from R using RJDBC/RHive

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, rjdbc

I'm using RJDBC 0.2-5 to connect to Hive in Rstudio. My server has hadoop-2.4.1 and hive-0.14. I follow the below mention steps to connect to Hive.

```
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
.jinit(parameters="-DrJava.debug=true")
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", 
            c("/home/packages/hive/New folder3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hive-jdbc-0.14.0.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hive-metastore-0.14.0.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hive-service-0.14.0.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/libfb303-0.9.0.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/libthrift-0.9.0.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/log4j-1.2.16.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar",
              "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hive-common-0.14.0.jar",
            "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hadoop-core-0.20.2.jar",
            "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hive-serde-0.14.0.jar",
             "/home/packages/hive/New folder3/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar"),
            identifier.quote="`")

conHive <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive://myserver:10000/default",
                  "usr",
                  "pwd")
```

But I am always getting the following error:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect",
>   as.character(url)[1],  :    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf$ConfVars

Even I tried with different version of Hive jar, Hive-jdbc-standalone.jar but nothing seems to work.. I also use RHive to connect to Hive but there was also no success.

Can anyone help me?.. I kind of stuck :(

Answer (score 7):

I didn't try rHive because it seems to need a complex installation on all the nodes of the cluster.

I successfully connect to Hive using RJDBC, here are a code snipet that works on my Hadoop 2.6 CDH5.4 cluster :

```
#loading libraries
library("DBI")
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

#init of the classpath (works with hadoop 2.6 on CDH 5.4 installation)
cp = c("/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar", "/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-common.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-service.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar")
.jinit(classpath=cp)

#initialisation de la connexion
drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc.jar", identifier.quote="`")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/mydb", "myuser", "")

#working with the connexion
show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
show_databases
```

The harder is to find all the needs jars and where to find them ...

**UPDATE**
The hive standalone JAR contains all that was needed to use Hive, using this standalone JAR with the hadoop-common jar is enough to use Hive.

So this is a simplified version, no need to worry to other jars that the hadoop-common and the hive-standalone jars.

```
 #loading libraries
 library("DBI")
 library("rJava")
 library("RJDBC")

 #init of the classpath (works with hadoop 2.6 on CDH 5.4 installation)
 cp = c("/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-common.jar", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar")
 .jinit(classpath=cp)

 #initialisation de la connexion
 drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-jdbc-standalone.jar", identifier.quote="`")
 conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/mydb", "myuser", "")

 #working with the connexion
 show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
 show_databases
```

Comment: Thanks loicmathieu for your reply.. I have taken all the jars from the lib directory of Hive & hadoop that are installed on my server. Also Two thing is different here, one is I am trying to connect to remote server rather than local. second is Hive2 is not configured on my server & I had to use hive in the Conn parameter( "jdbc:hive://myserver:10000/....) Can you suggest further ?

Comment: Hi, I also connect to a remote Hive (I use localhost as example) but via Hive2 server. You can try the same way as I but with the org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver driver and the jdbc URl you use. The main part here is to define a correct classpath and calling .jinit with it (in your example you don't use the same initialisation code as myself). So I suggest you to use the same way to init rJava that in my example (defining cp then callin .jinit()), I just add one by one all the needed jars util I have no more NoClassDefFoundError ...

Comment: I also follow the same that you mentioned but again stuck with the same error. However when I checked the Hive-common-0.14.jar, HiveConf class file is present with appropriate package. not sure why JVM is not considering this. Even I checked the my JVM version with the JVM version on which this jar file is created. Mine is newer than Jar's JVM So there should not be any issue :(

Comment: The order of these statements mattered for me. 
`library("DBI")
library("rJava")
library("RJDBC")

drv <- JDBC("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver", "<path to directory containing jars>/hive-jdbc.jar", identifier.quote="\`")

.jclassLoader()$setDebug(1L)

for(l in list.files('<path to directory containing jars>')){ .jaddClassPath(paste("<path to directory containing jars>", l , sep=""))}

conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://<ip>:10000/<dbname>", "username", "password")

show_databases <- dbGetQuery(conn, "show databases")
show_databases`

Comment: Also, here's the list of jars that I used `hadoop-common.jar  hive-service.jar  libthrift-0.9.3.jar  slf4j-log4j12.jar
hive-jdbc-standalone.jar httpclient-4.2.5.jar  log4j-1.2.17.jar
hive-jdbc.jar   httpcore-4.2.5.jar  slf4j-api.jar`

Comment: It was not working for me also when connected from remote.  I simply copied the driver files to the R host and replaced the above paths. And it worked !!!!  The files i coped :  hive-jdbc-1.2.0-mapr-1707-standalone.jar,   hadoop-common-2.7.0-mapr-1703.jar

Comment: I also follow the code and for CDH 5.9, the jars are hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.9.1.jar and hive-jdbc-1.1.1-standalone.jar

Answer (score 0):

Ioicmathieu's answer works for me now after I have switched to an older hive jar for example from 3.1.1 to 2.0.0.

Unfortunately I can't comment on his answer that's why I have written another one.

If you run into the following error try an older version:

> Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect",
>   as.character(url)[1],  :    java.sql.SQLException: Could not open
>   client transport with JDBC Uri:
>   jdbc:hive2://host_name: Could not establish
>   connection to jdbc:hive2://host_name:10000: Required
>   field 'client_protocol' is unset!
>   Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null,
>   configuration:{set:hiveconf:hive.server2.thrift.resultset.default.fetch.size=1000,
>   use:database=default})

Comment: I'm not asking a question, I'm giving a hint for an error people might encounter when they use the first answer and point to a possible solution as well.